# DDR4 Routing Consideration

Tags: pcb-design, memory, layout, ddr, ddr4

I'm designing a new PC based on Intel Tiger Lake UP3.

In Intel Design Guide, I saw that there recommendation for DDR4 signals is to have two BO segments (BO1 and BO2).
each BO has different impedance and length consideration.
what's the reason behind this?
why there is no straight line from Via 1 to Via 2 through the M (Main Trace) segment?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question intrigues me. I hope someone will answer your question.